# Error in update and upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, software-center, update-manager

Following are some of the errors that I am getting while using the command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

W: Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/Release.gpg  Could not connect to pk.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (58.65.218.244). - connect (110: Connection timed out)
W: Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/source/Sources  Unable to connect to pk.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: you can refer to this link : http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/ubuntu-13-04-apt-get-update-problems-4175460316/

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this command

> **sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update**

to clean the cache (and partially downloaded files) and then update your package lists.